# Center Bootstrap Modal horizontal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

In my Angular program, I'm trying to center my Bootstrap 3 Modal horizontally on the screen. I've tried everything I've seen and I've tried `text-align: center` and `align = "center"` and I can't get it to work. How can I center it?

Here's an abbreviated version of my modal:

```html
<div class="col-xs-10" style="padding-top: 50px;">

  <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-8" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title pull-left" style="width: 300px;">Add New Employee</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <fieldset>

          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-xs-5" style="padding-left: 0px"> Employee ID </label>
              <div class="col-xs-7">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empID" [(ngModel)]="newEmp.EmpID" name="empID" placeholder="Employee ID" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </fieldset>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

and here's where it's called:

```html
<div id="addNewEmployeeModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="form" aria-labelledby="myNewEmployeeModal" aria-hidden="true">
 <pto-add-new (updateEmpInfo)="onUpdateEmpInfo($event)" (updateSelectedEmployee)="onUpdateSelectedEmployee($event)"></pto-add-new>
</div>
```

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I've tried everything that I've seen on here and none of it works. I'm not sure if I'm putting the attributes on the wrong `div` or what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Here's how it shows up in the browser]

Comment: Is that all of the html code that is inside `modal-dialog` or `modal-content`? It would be better if you post the rendered html.

Comment: set width  `width:50%;`

Comment: @SuneelKumar in my css or on a specific div?

Comment: try setting max-width on Modal Dialog and margin auto attribute...

Comment: @rcarc inline style

Comment: Set `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` on the most outer div in your modal, most likely the one that has the `modal` class. If it is `block` displayed, this will center it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `col-xs-10` so:

By col-md-offset-1 or col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-offset-3 You move element by X columns to right. Because You modal do not take whole 12 columns, You must move it by 2 to right.

From bootstrap 3.1 offset do not work for XS columns.

.col-xs-offset-* doesn't exist. Offset and column ordering are only for small and more. (ONLY .col-sm-offset-*, .col-md-offset-* and .col-lg-offset-*)

Soo:

You can use SM or MD column or set element as `display:inline-block;` and to container for modal set `text-align:center;`

```
<div class="my_modal_container" style="padding-top: 50px;">

  <div class="panel panel-default my_modal_panel">
```

CSS:

```
.my_modal_container{
   text-align:center;
}
.my_modal_panel{
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:left; // or other
}
```